Input range - position each step
I have horizontal points with months.
Above points, I would like to create a shape (ship) that you can drag to the next steps.
A few points are grouped to display the same slide.
The gap between points is 10px and each point has width 29px.
I would like that my ship icon will start on the left side of the point (circle).
https://prnt.sc/ngT2ApoiAV5f


function updateSliderOffset($inputRange, inputValue) {
  const circleWidth = 29;
  const gapWidth = 10;
  const totalWidth = circleWidth + gapWidth;
  const offset = totalWidth * inputValue;

  $inputRange.get(0).style.setProperty("--slider-offset", `${offset}px`);
}

function componentCalendar() {
  $(".pd-calendar-heading").animate({}, function() {
    let $calendarHeading = $(this),
      $block = $calendarHeading.closest(".pd-block");
    let $calendarUnits = $calendarHeading.find(".pd-calendar-units");
    let $calendarContent = $block.find(".pd-calendar-content"),
      $calendarSlider = $calendarContent.find(".pd-calendar-slider__inner");


    let $inputRange = $calendarHeading.find(".pd-range-slider__input");

    $calendarUnits
      .find('.pd-calendar-unit[data-calendar-index="1"]')
      .addClass("active")
      .parent(".pd-calendar-units__group")
      .addClass("active");

    $calendarUnits.on("click", ".pd-calendar-unit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();


      let $unitElem = $(this),
        unitIndex = parseInt($unitElem.data("calendar-index")),
        inputValue = unitIndex - 1,
        unitSlideIndex = $unitElem.data("slide-index");

      $inputRange.val(inputValue);
      $calendarSlider.slick("slickGoTo", unitSlideIndex);

      updateSliderOffset($inputRange, inputValue);
    });

    $calendarSlider
      .slick({
        arrows: true,
        fade: true,
      })
      .on("beforeChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        let $nextSlide = $(slick.$slides.get(nextSlide)),
        nextSlideIndex = $nextSlide.find('.pd-calendar-slide').attr('data-calendar-index'),
        inputValue = nextSlideIndex - 1;

        $calendarUnits
          .find(".pd-calendar-unit[data-calendar-index]")
          .removeClass("active")
          .parent(".pd-calendar-units__group, .pd-calendar-units__group")
          .removeClass("active");

        $calendarUnits
          .find(
            '.pd-calendar-unit[data-calendar-index="' + nextSlideIndex + '"]'
          )
          .addClass("active")
          .parent(".pd-calendar-units__group")
          .addClass("active");

        $inputRange.val(inputValue);
        updateSliderOffset($inputRange, inputValue);
      });



    $inputRange.on("input", function() {
      let $input = $(this),
        inputValue = parseInt($input.val()),
        unitNumber = inputValue + 1;

      let $unitElem = $calendarUnits.find(
          '.pd-calendar-unit[data-calendar-index="' + unitNumber + '"]'
        ),
        unitSlideIndex = $unitElem.data("slide-index");

      $calendarSlider.slick("slickGoTo", unitSlideIndex);
      updateSliderOffset($input, inputValue);
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  componentCalendar();
});
.pd-calendar-units {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 18px;
  padding-top: 45px;
  position: relative;
}
.pd-calendar-units .pd-range-slider {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 1160px;
}
.pd-calendar-units .pd-range-slider__input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pd-calendar-units .pd-range-slider__input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: orange;
  height: 5px;
}
.pd-calendar-units .pd-range-slider__input::-moz-range-track {
  background: orange;
  height: 5px;
}
.pd-calendar-units .pd-range-slider__input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  width: 66px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' data-name='Layer 1' viewBox='0 0 75 23'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23238dc1' d='m9.3 16.5-5-5h62.5l-5 5m-46-5V1h6v10.5m3 0v-4h34.5v4m-51-.5V7h5v4'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23238dc1' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.5 15.4c.2 3.6 3.2 6.4 6.8 6.4s6.6-2.8 6.8-6.4h1c-.3 4.1-3.7 7.3-7.9 7.3S.7 19.5.5 15.4h1Z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23238dc1' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M16.1 15.4c.2 3.6 3.2 6.4 6.8 6.4s6.6-2.8 6.8-6.4h1c-.3 4.1-3.7 7.3-7.9 7.3s-7.5-3.2-7.7-7.3h1Z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23238dc1' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M30.7 15.4c.2 3.6 3.2 6.4 6.8 6.4s6.6-2.8 6.8-6.4h1c-.3 4.1-3.7 7.3-7.9 7.3s-7.5-3.2-7.7-7.3h1Z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23238dc1' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M45.2 15.4c.2 3.6 3.2 6.4 6.8 6.4s6.6-2.8 6.8-6.4h1c-.3 4.1-3.7 7.3-7.9 7.3s-7.5-3.2-7.7-7.3h1Z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23238dc1' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M59.9 15.4c.2 3.6 3.2 6.4 6.8 6.4s6.6-2.8 6.8-6.4h1c-.3 4.1-3.7 7.3-7.9 7.3s-7.5-3.2-7.7-7.3h1Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  transform: translateX(var(--slider-offset));
}
.pd-calendar-units__inner, .pd-calendar-units__group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}
.pd-calendar-units__inner {
  width: 100%;
}
.pd-calendar-units__group {
  position: relative;
}
.pd-calendar-units__group.active .pd-calendar-unit.group-first-element .pd-calendar-unit__circle {
  background-color: blue;
}
.pd-calendar-units__group.active .pd-calendar-unit.group-first-element ~ .pd-calendar-unit .pd-calendar-unit__circle {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.pd-calendar-units__group.active .pd-calendar-unit.group-first-element ~ .pd-calendar-unit:last-child .pd-calendar-unit__circle {
  background-color: blue;
}
.pd-calendar-units__group.active .pd-calendar-unit.group-first-element ~ .pd-calendar-unit:last-child .pd-calendar-unit__name {
  color: blue;
}

.pd-calendar-unit {
  text-orientation: mixed;
}
.pd-calendar-unit__inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}
.pd-calendar-unit__inner > * {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.pd-calendar-unit__circle {
  content: "";
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  width: 29px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.pd-calendar-unit__name {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}
.pd-calendar-unit:hover .pd-calendar-unit__circle {
  background-color: blue;
}
.pd-calendar-unit:hover .pd-calendar-unit__name {
  color: blue;
}
.pd-calendar-unit.active .pd-calendar-unit__circle {
  background-color: blue;
}
.pd-calendar-unit.active .pd-calendar-unit__name {
  color: blue;
}

.pd-calendar-slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 21px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.pd-calendar-slider__inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.pd-calendar-slide {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 30px 21px;
}
.pd-calendar-slide__inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 20px;
}
.pd-calendar-slide__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}

.pd-calendar-event {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 2px;
}
.pd-calendar-event *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.pd-calendar-event__label, .pd-calendar-event__text {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.31;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: black;
}

/* Slider */
.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.slick-track:before, .slick-track:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  display: none;
}
[dir=rtl] .slick-slide {
  float: right;
}
.slick-slide img {
  display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
  display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class="pd-block">
  <div class="pd-calendar-heading">
    <div class="pd-calendar-units">
      <div class="pd-range-slider">
        <input class="pd-range-slider__input" name="unit-value" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="29" step="1">

      </div>

      <div class="pd-calendar-units__inner">

        <div class="pd-calendar-units__group">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit group-first-element" data-calendar-index="1" data-slide-index="0">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                February </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="2" data-slide-index="0">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                March </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="3" data-slide-index="1">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
              April </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pd-calendar-units__group">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit group-first-element" data-calendar-index="4" data-slide-index="2">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                May </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="5" data-slide-index="2">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                June </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-units__group">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit group-first-element" data-calendar-index="6" data-slide-index="3">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                July </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="7" data-slide-index="3">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                August </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="8" data-slide-index="4">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
              September </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pd-calendar-units__group">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit group-first-element" data-calendar-index="9" data-slide-index="5">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                October </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="10" data-slide-index="5">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                November </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="11" data-slide-index="5">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                December </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="12" data-slide-index="5">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                January </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="13" data-slide-index="5">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                February </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="14" data-slide-index="6">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
              March </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pd-calendar-units__group">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit group-first-element" data-calendar-index="15" data-slide-index="7">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                April </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="16" data-slide-index="7">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                May </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="17" data-slide-index="7">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                June </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="18" data-slide-index="7">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                July </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="19" data-slide-index="7">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                August </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="20" data-slide-index="7">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                September </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="21" data-slide-index="7">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                October </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="22" data-slide-index="8">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
              November </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pd-calendar-units__group">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit group-first-element" data-calendar-index="23" data-slide-index="9">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                December </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="24" data-slide-index="9">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                January </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="25" data-slide-index="9">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                February </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="26" data-slide-index="9">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                March </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-units__group">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit group-first-element" data-calendar-index="27" data-slide-index="10">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                April </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="28" data-slide-index="10">
            <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
              <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
                May </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="29" data-slide-index="11">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
              June </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pd-calendar-unit" data-calendar-index="30" data-slide-index="11">
          <div class="pd-calendar-unit__inner">
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__circle"></span>
            <span class="pd-calendar-unit__name">
              July </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pd-calendar-content">
    <div class="pd-calendar-slider">
      <div class="pd-calendar-slider__inner">
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="1">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">February-March:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 1</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="3">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">April:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 3</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="4">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">May-June:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 4</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="6">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">July-August:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 6</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="8">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">September:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 8</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="9">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">October-February:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 9</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="14">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">March:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 14</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="15">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">April-October:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 15</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="22">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">November:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 22</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="23">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">December-March:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 23</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="27">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">April-May:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 27</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-calendar-slide" data-calendar-index="29">
          <div class="pd-calendar-slide__inner">

            <div class="pd-calendar-slide__content">
              <div class="pd-calendar-event">
                <div class="pd-calendar-event__content">
                  <span class="pd-calendar-event__label">June:</span>
                  <div class="pd-calendar-event__text">Example Text 29</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



Codepen link: https://codepen.io/matteokrr/pen/xxoqXMo
I tried to use translateX() and calculate the distance from left based on the input value.

"I would like that my ship icon will start on the left side of the point (circle)" - If you do that (perhaps with a translate: -58px), the ship will start mostly offscreen. You should widen the whole thing with space either side for a starting space.
